# PHP Compiled but phpinfo() Shows Old Version

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, centos5

I am attempting to upgrade PHP from 5.2 to 5.3 on CentOS, but phpinfo() is still claiming PHP 5.2 is installed.

A built PHP by compiling Apache 1.3 and then building PHP using apxs:

```
# cd ../php-5.3.29
# ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache-php/bin/apxs --with-mysql=/usr/include/mysql --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --enable-mbstring --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --with-curl=/usr
# make
# make test
# make install
```

This seemed to work. I restarted the whole server, and then started Apache like so:

```
/usr/local/apache-php/bin/httpd -f /path/to/httpd.conf -D PERLDB -DSSL
```

Apache is working, and the Apache module server status is returning a build date for Apache of 16 September 2014, which is correct. However, phpinfo() is displaying this:

```
PHP Version 5.2.6
Build Date Mar 6 2014
Configure Command './configure' '--with-apxs=/usr/local/apache-centosssl-php/bin/apxs' '--with-mysql=/usr/include/mysql' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir' '--with-png-dir' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-mysqli' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-curl=/usr'
```

/usr/local/apache-centosssl-php/ is the path to the previous build of Apache, compiled in March 2014, for PHP 5.2. It seems that Apache is starting up and using some old files from my previous PHP compilation?

On the command line, I get:

```
# php -v
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Sep 16 2014 16:53:53) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

I have searched php.ini and httpd.conf for "apache-centosssl-php" and there are zero occurrences.

Comment: Is the new version installed over the old version, or is it installed to a new location? If you installed PHP to a new location, have you updated the Apache configuration to use the new PHP?

Comment: i am not totaly sure but apache runs php as a module so if the 5.2 module still there you need to change it. like i said, i am not sure maybe my know-how is a lil bit old.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that I was using a symlink in Apache to link to the PHP module:

```
libexec -> /usr/local/apache-centosssl-php/libexec
```

I modified that to

```
libexec -> /usr/local/apache-php/libexec
```

It seems to be working now.